# Android: getting data from php page

Tags: php, android, html

I use this code to do it:

```
textUrl = new URL(url);
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream(), "utf-8"));
            String StringBuffer;

            while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringText += StringBuffer;
            }
            bufferReader.close();
            return stringText;
```

**But** this will give me the data as html code. So, I must parse the html code.
**My problem is:**
If I have

```
<?php echo 1; ?>
```

it only **1** byte. but with my code it will be **100** bytes for example caused by html code and i will lost bandwidth on nothing after I parse the html code.
**My question is:** Can I get the result from the php page without the html code? So, I can get `1` not `<html><body>1</body></html>`

Comment: return data in JSON or XML format.

Comment: @DroidDev its plain text.

Comment: Hi.  
You're not using a connection class like `HttpsURLConnection`.  
To start communicating with your server you should check this: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html
  
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

use regex: `preg_match("\<body>([^>]+)<\/body>\", $html, $matched);`

echo $matched[1][0];